# angular-auth-oidc-client --> silentRenewHeartBeatCheck runs every 3-4 seconds

Tags: angular-auth-oidc-client

Is the silentRenewHeartBeatCheck supposed to run every 3-4 seconds?  I just want to know if I configured something wrong or not.  I don't even know where to look to check for something that would configure this.  If it is doing what it is supposed to be doing I won't worry about it.

In just a few minutes I've got 150 of these in chrome dev tools console:

`silentRenewHeartBeatCheck
    silentRenewRunning: true
    idToken: true
    _userData.value: true`

Early on in my log I also get the below error as well but no idea what is causing it except I'm assuming it has something to do with the silent renew iframe running, but maybe not:

`Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit while the tab is in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is foregrounded. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code here: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/src/services/oidc.security.service.ts.

Unfortunately, it's hard-coded to run every three seconds and there is no configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as the `silentRenewHeartBeatCheck` message issue:**

In your `OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration` make sure `log_console_debug_active` is set to `false`. That will stop the `silentRenewHeartBeatCheck` messages in your console.